# Save Gtk.DrawingArea to Bitmap

Tags: drawing, monodevelop, gtk#

I need to save image of my DrawingArea object to Bitmap, but I can't find how to do it. Can anybody tell, how save DrawingArea image to Bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, it depends exactly what you want to do and whether/why you really need a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

**Copy the Widget**

You can P/Invoke [gtk_widget_get_snapshot](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-get-snapshot) to get a `Gdk.Pixbuf`.

The Pixbuf can be can be saved into a a file, or copied into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.

**Using System.Drawing**

You could port your drawing code to the System.Drawing API.

In your DrawingArea's `Expose` method, use [Gtk.DotNet.Graphics.FromDrawable](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.DotNet.Graphics%2fM%2fFromDrawable) to get a `System.Drawing.Graphics` for your widget and draw onto that using your ported drawing code.

Then, you can create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and use the same drawing code to draw to it.

**Using Cairo**

You could port your drawing code to `Mono.Cairo` (the new GTK# drawing APIs, which are much more powerful than System.Drawing).

In your DrawingArea's `Expose` method, use `Gdk.CairoHelper.Create` to get a Cairo context for your widget and draw onto that using your ported drawing code.

Then, you can use your Cairo drawing logic to write to a Cairo `ImageSurface`, which can be saved into a a file, or copied into a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.